it's ensured but conitnue with error - Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>
I'm having trouble in my index.jsx and _layout.jsx in my expo app with react native. I tried to do some things but any of then worked for me.

index.js

import store from '../redux/store.js';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import RootLayout from './_layout.jsx';
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';

const Index = () => {
    <Provider store={store}>
      <RootLayout />
    </Provider>
}

registerRootComponent(Index);



_layout.jsx

import '../assets/color.js'
import { Tabs } from "expo-router";
import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons' 
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import LoadingScreen from "../components/loading.jsx";
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';



export default function RootLayout() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function iniciarApp() {
      try {
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
        dispatch(loadInitialData());
        setIsLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Erro de inicialização:', error);
      }
    }

    iniciarApp();
  }, [dispatch]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <LoadingScreen />;
  }



  return (

      // autenticação
        <Tabs
          screenOptions={{
            tabBarActiveTintColor: '#005335',
            tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'gray',
          }}
          initialRouteName='/'
          
        >

          {/* tela home */}
          <Tabs.Screen name="home/index"
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
              title: 'Home',
              tabBarIcon: ({ focused, size }) => (
                <FontAwesome name="home" color={focused ? colors.green : 'gray'} size={size}/>
              )
            
          }}  />
        </Tabs>
  );
}


store.js

import { combineReducers, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import user from "./slices/user";
import box from "./slices/box";

const reducer = combineReducers({
    user,
    box,
});

export default configureStore({ reducer });

I tried to AppRegistry and put the provider in _layout.jsx directly but nothing works. I just need the worflow of redux work and then i can continue with my project.

This question is similar to: useDispatch() Error: Could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a . If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
